# Making automatic email reminder using VBA

Tags: vba, email, ms-access

I am trying to make email using Outlook to remind someone to update their CV information per 6 months (180 days).

I have 1 query and 1 table.
Duedate_7 query consists of employee information, which passed 180 days or more since the last update. Access would send email to those employees.
Highlights table consists of the ID of the employees (Number), date of the project (date) and content of the project (long text).

```vb
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Function Otomail()
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset

Dim emailTo As String
Dim emailSubject As String
Dim emailText As String
 
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outlookStarted As Boolean

On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If outApp Is Nothing Then
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    outlookStarted = True
End If
       
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs1 = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, NIK, Nama, email, datemailsend FROM DueDate_7")

Do Until rs1.EOF

    emailTo = rs1.Fields("email")
    
    emailSubject = "Update CV"
    
    emailText = "Please send the newest project highlights informations of Mr/Mrs' " & rs1.Fields("Nama").Value & " to the inside sales department for updating your CV which is scheduled once per 6 months." & vbCr & _
                "Your latest project highlights update was " & vbCr & _
                "This email is auto generated from Task Database. Please Do Not Reply!"
    
    Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    outMail.To = emailTo
    outMail.Subject = emailSubject
    outMail.Body = emailText
    outMail.Display
    
    rs1.Edit
    rs1!datemailsend = Date
    rs1.Update
    
    rs1.MoveNext
    
Loop

rs1.Close

Set rs1 = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

Set outMail = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing

End Function
```

I want to include each of the employee's 3 latest project highlights, stored in Highlights table, in each of the email I send.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is to use a second recordset inside the loop that you have already got that selects the information required. Something like:

```
    If Not (rs1.BOF And rs1.EOF) Then
        Do
            
            strProject = ""
            strSQL = "SELECT TOP 3 ProjectName, ProjectDate " _
                & " FROM Highlights " _
                & " WHERE NameID=" & rs1!NameID _
                & " ORDER BY ProjectDate DESC;"
            Set rsProject = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
            If Not (rsProject.BOF And rsProject.EOF) Then
                Do
                    strProject = strProject & rsProject!ProjectDate & vbTab & rsProject!ProjectName & vbCrLf
                    rsProject.MoveNext
                Loop Until rsProject.EOF
            End If
            Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
            outMail.To = rs1!email
            outMail.Subject = "Update CV"
            outMail.Body = emailText & strProject
            outMail.Display
            rs1.MoveNext
        Loop Until rs1.EOF
    End If
```

This is assuming that you have a field called `NameID` that identifies the person to be selected.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried to put the codes you provided just right below Do Until rs1.EOF and get compile error : invalid use of propery at line strProject = "" .  What should I do?

Comment: The code that I have shown is only the snippet that goes inside the first recordset. So it is missing declarations (`Dim rsProject As DAO.Recordset:Dim strSQL As String: Dim strProject As String`

Comment: Okay, so now the immediate shows the correct records. But, I get run-time error 3021 : no current record at 'emailTo = rs1.Fields("email")'.  Also, how to include all three project highlights from strproject to the email text?

Comment: I've modified the code to include more of your original code that creates the email to show how it should all work together.

Comment: thank you so much! Now I understand how the codes work and it does what I intend to